# How to print barcode and QR code using a dot matrix print? (EPSON TM-U220)

Tags: c#, printing, barcode, qr-code, dot-matrix

I have a [dot matrix printer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_matrix_printer) capable of 180 dpi (EPSON TM-U220) and a C# WPF application for billing. It must print a ticket with a barcode and a QR code. I am using [zxing](https://zxingnet.codeplex.com/) to generate a barcode and a QR code and I just print it using [printDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The QR code and barcode are not readable using the scanner, unless they are printed with a very big size. Is there a way to print readable barcodes and QR codes using a dot matrix printer?

Comment: I don't think dot matrix printers have a fine enough detail to be able to do bar/qr codes without as you said, making it bigger. You may need to look into a thermal printer in order to keep the barcode size down. Good luck.